# Examples which use map reduce to process GIS data?

Tags: geoprocessing

Have anyone have a few examples how to use mapreduce effective with GIS data?

Comment: Are you referring to this? [MapReduce software framework by Google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)

Comment: You need to be more specific to what you exactly need...

Answer (score 8):

Some pointers from few first pages from [Google](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=mapreduce%20spatial%20data):

- [Parallel bulk-loading of spatial data with MapReduce: An R-tree case](http://www.springerlink.com/content/41637x62364h5272/) (paywall)
- [SJMR:Parallelizing Spatial Join with MapReduce on Clusters](http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/%7Ezxu/papers/cluster09.pdf)
- [Voronoi-Based Geospatial Query Processing with MapReduce](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mapreduce%20spatial%20data&source=web&cd=18&ved=0CFoQFjAHOAo&url=http://vlab.asu.edu:8080/attachments/106/Voronoi-Based_Geospatial_Query_Processing_with_MapReduce_.pdf&ei=fOzgTu_5JITK8gPclq25Bw&usg=AFQjCNFAsu8d-yqWpVWTSCytKF4MSg5NGQ&cad=rja)
- [Accelerating Spatial Data Processing with MapReduce](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5695607/;jsessionid=LmLGvUONqo7oMeoPd0DnRTs_8pBDWHbWshLUZXlr_NuDrs-WHKxV!624181834) (paywall)
- [Indexing Geospatial Data with MapReduce](https://web.archive.org/web/20161001193657/https://wiki.umiacs.umd.edu/ccc/images/8/8f/CLuE-Rishe.pdf)
- [Experiences on Processing Spatial Data with MapReduce](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/%7Evagelis/publications/Spatial-MapReduce-SSDBM2009.pdf)
- [SDPPF — A MapReduce based parallel processing framework for spatial data](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6057775/;jsessionid=durGvbWrc4GVPwNqX0Mg_dUd_nB0xQEnfP2bRHWIJ5ALo9hP_F0T!-224115674)
- [Spatial Queries Evaluation with MapReduce](https://web.archive.org/web/20110516231358/http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/GCC.2009.16) (paywall)
- [Tiled-MapReduce: Optimizing Resource Usages of Data-parallel Applications on Multicore with Tiling](http://www.cslu.ogi.edu/%7Ezak/cs506-pslc/tiledmr.pdf)
- [MRGIS: A MapReduce-Enabled High Performance Workﬂow System for GIS](http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/%7Elwang7/papers/Wang-GISWorkflow.pdf)

Do you have any particular application in mind?

Comment: The article "Voronoi-Baskin Geospatial Query Processing with MapReduce" is no longer available, but Google has a cached HTML version of it. Here is the updated link: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://vlab.asu.edu:8080/attachments/106/Voronoi-Based_Geospatial_Query_Processing_with_MapReduce_.pdf

Comment: It seems to be a list of of research articles. Some are probably interesting, but I don't know if geo raster aggregation have been done in practice at high throughput. For example, HDFS doesn't seem to support random read operations which can make processing inefficient